# Pass a multidimensional array from jsp to controller

Tags: jquery, arrays, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am creating an update page where I am using jquery to create an 2 dimensional array which consists of updated propertyName and the old value. I am doing this so that I do not need to check on server for updated properties. This updatedParam variable I need to pass it to Spring controller. How should this be done? This variable is not part of the model backed form.

I have tried the following in the controller, but it does not work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEmployee.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEmployee(                       
        BindingResult result, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
        ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "updatedParam") Map<String,String> updatedParam) {
```

I even tried this but even it does not work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEmployee.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateEmployee(                       
        BindingResult result, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
        ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "updatedParam") String[][] updatedParam) {
```

NOTE: updatedParam is the variable which I generated in my jsp and which I wish to pass when I call this action on form submission.

Also please note the form submission code

```
$("#updateEmployeeForm").submit(function(){
    //Compute updatedParam Here
    // I tried submiting the form using ajax and passing updated param as data but does not work 

});
```

Please advise. In firebug console I keep getting the following error message but I do not think its related to this

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: It's not easy to handle arrays with spring-mvc. I think, you should better put all your data into a new class instance and pass this as RequestBody/ResponseBody.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you send the form data AND the updated fields?  And why would you you use an array for an object with a well defined structure? If it's property name -> value than it's a map. Apart from that a client could send false data. Relying on the client is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this so that I do not need to check on server for updated properties.

**This is wrong.**

You should **always** check on server everything that is send by user.
Client side validation is not sufficient, as client can easily fool it.

What I'd recommend is simply to make `propertyName` a part of form backing object and validate it server side.