# Design approach for update form page in my website

Tags: java, jquery, forms, spring-mvc

I am currently working on a update page where I will provide the user with his details pre populated in the form. I am using Spring MVC and JSP/Jquery. I would like to know the best approach to handle form updated. I have the following two approaches:

1. Since the form is pretty big. Using JQuery I am populating a variable which will only contain the updated or edit fields from the form. But using this approach I am stuck and I have posted this question for the same: [Pass a multidimensional array from jsp to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854304/pass-a-multidimensional-array-from-jsp-to-controller)
2. I compare the two objects in the controller itself and identify the updated fields, log them and save the updated values. I did not want to use this one at first because it would mean additional computation at the server side.

Are there any other design approaches to handle update form pages which might be useful in my case?

Comment: Relying on the client is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer for your second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854304/pass-a-multidimensional-array-from-jsp-to-controller).

@zeroflagL is right, **don't rely on client-side validation**.

Approach 2 is much better.